# Progress bar on synchronious operations in Mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, attributes

I have long synchronious calls to MainFrame in my Mvc 3 application 
I'd like to create a custom Attribute that will decorate My controller actions which I know can take long time. And if controller is decorated with this attribute I need to render "loading message"

Any Ideas please , could it be achieved ?